# Fishing Safe Puzzle

Tags: wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle

My friend has come down with a fever, and asked me to retrieve his anniversary present for him. It's a song he wrote for his wife called "Ja, vi elsker dette landet". I went to the fishing supplies shop he owns, but can't open the safe (number pad). The Nyquil must have knocked him out, because he won't answer his phone. The clock is ticking, and all I can do is look in despair at signs around the shop...

> "Pretty fly for a fish guy" What?
>
> "Cod is wonderful bait for tuna!" No it isn't!
>
> "Ceci n'est pas red herring" How treacherous!
>
> "Roe roe roe your boat..." Useless!

Maybe you guys can figure out the 4 digit code?

Comment: Are you sure [cryptic-clues] is accurate here? That tag is for clues in the style of cryptic crosswords, where each one splits into definition and wordplay.

Comment: @deusovi no, I'm not sure I have the best tag. Maybe it should be wordplay?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is right because it ignores a large portion of the given information, but could the code be

> **1842**?

I noticed that

> the second line, when spoken out loud, hides several spoken numerals:
>
>  "Cod is **won**derful (1) b**ait** (8) **for** (4) **tu**na! (2)"
>
>  Also note that "cod" is one letter away from "code," so the line might be a mnemonic for the code, which would be 1842.

The only problem is that

> this doesn't use any information from the other three lines or the flavortext, and I might be missing something from them. Perhaps, as the third line cryptically suggests, they're all just red herrings except of course for the second. But I don't know for sure.

Comment: rot13(Whfg nqqvat fbzr vagrerfgvat vasbezngvba, 1842 nyfb frrzf gb or gur lrne va juvpu gur jevgre bs "Føaare ni Abetr" ( juvpu jnf gur angvbany nagurz bs Abejnl nebhaq 1820 gb gur rneyl 20gu praghel) cnffrq njnl, naq yngre ba  "Wn, iv ryfxre qrggr ynaqrg" orpnzr gur arj angvbany nagurz. (Nyy zl vasb pbzrf sebz n dhvpx tbbtyr frnepu fb V znl unir snpgf jebat naq jvyy or or unccl gb or pbeerpgrq ol nalbar gung xabjf zber))

Comment: Yes, that's opened the safe! After knowing him for so long, I should've realized ROT13(Zl sevraq vf Evxneq Abeqennx (fbat'f pbzcbfre). Evpxl fvzcyl hfrq uvf ovegu lrne sbe gur cnffjbeq, naq uvq vg pelcgvpnyyl va gur fvta whfg nf lbh sbhaq vg!). As for the third block you wrote, you are mostly correct. Joke info was given to create a distraction, and while the flavor is hiding some deep dove information that wouldn't give you the answer alone, but could help confirm the answer on the sign. Good job!

Answer (score 2):

I spent way too much time trying to decipher a bunch of stuff, between languages and substitutions. I hope this isn't the answer, since it would be a slap in the face, but my answer is

> 2213, based entirely on number of fish references per line

Per line analysis:

> "Pretty **fly** for a **fish** guy" What? - Fly fishing and, well, fish = 2
>  "**Cod** is wonderful bait for **tuna**!" No it isn't! - 2 types of fish
>  "Ceci n'est pas **red herring**" How treacherous! - 1 type of fish
>  "**Roe roe roe** your boat..." Useless! - Fish eggs x3

Also, your friend wrote the Norwegian national anthem for his wife? Pretty impressive.

Comment: That code is not opening the door. He did write the anthem for his wife! I wonder if he used a significant date as the code to the vault?